# How do I use Solana.kt library in Android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, solana

I'm trying to import Solana.kt library - https://github.com/ajamaica/Solana.kt
into my android project, so I could try creating solana wallet/sending tokens. I'm noob, so I can't figure out how do I go exactly adding library into the project and then how to I use it? (For example from my MainActivity I want to click button to create wallet). Library code is like this - [image]

So my main questions are

- how to import it properly? (since there is no direct gradle "implement" option)
- how do I call library method from my MainActivity?

[image: settings.gradle]

[image: build.gradle part1]
[image: build.gradle part2]
[image: build.gradle part3]
[image: build.gradle part4]
Thank you for your insights.

Comment: What does your build.gradle file look like? Are you seeing any errors? Provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps to include the local SDK to your own project:

1. Copy `solana` folder to your main project folder (*ctrl+c & ctrl+v*)
2. Open settings.gradle file and put this piece of code

`include ':app', ':solana'`

`project(':solana').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'solana')`

3. After that open the app `build.gradle` file and put this:

`implementation project(path: ':solana')`

If your version of configure files are suitable with sdk files, this should work

Comment: And how to I call methods from libraby on mainactivity? For example button click to call method in library?